# fixed-fluid-fluid layout with equal column height

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I'm trying to build a three-column page with a fixed-fluid-fluid layout and equal column heights.

I found this:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-32-fluid-fluid-fixed/

it got me most of the way, but the columns aren't equal height.

I've also tried using CSS tables and it works except when scaling, the columns overlap.

Any ideas?

Edit: I was able to make this work just fine using CSS tables. I preferred that method for making the columns equal height anyway. The overlapping columns, it turns out, was a result of some floated content in my fixed left column. When I removed the float, the page scaled fine.

Comment: can you provide a test page with what you tried here http://jsfiddle.net or http://codepen.io/pen or at least your html and css ?

Comment: here's the version with equal heights, but overlapping columns: http://jsfiddle.net/tpRQL/